# How to append attribute to objectClass LDAP

Tags: ldap

Is there a way to append an attribute to objectClass?

I'm using LDAP Account Manager (LAM) v5.6

My objectClass:

```
olcObjectClasses: ( 2.25.123456789.20 
NAME 'helloOBJnew' 
DESC 'helloOBJ desc v2' 
SUP top 
AUXILIARY 
MAY (attr) )
```

I want to append this attribute to that class:

```
olcAttributeClasses: ( 2.25.123456789.10 
NAME 'newAttr' 
EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch 
SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringMath 
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )
```

I want to get this result:

```
olcObjectClasses: ( 2.25.123456789.20 
NAME 'helloOBJnew' 
DESC 'helloOBJ desc v2' 
SUP top 
AUXILIARY 
MAY (attr $ newAttr) )
```

Also - do I lose all data of attr in existing entries when appending the new attribute?

P.S.
Don't mind about naming and oids